# Strategy for being able to reverse a deletion using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a series of related tables maintained by Python/SQLAlchemy. If I delete a row in a particular table, I want the ability to be able to reverse that delete at some point in the future, in case of a mistake. I could do this using an is_deleted column and filter on that, but that becomes a pain when I'm querying other tables for related data. I could add an is_deleted column to all the other tables, and when a row from the main table is deleted, toggle them all. But then for every query on all the tables I'd have to filter on is_deleted. It can be done, but I'm hoping there's a better strategy.

One thought would be to move all the deleted data to another set of tables, that only store deleted data. But it's unclear to me if SQLAlchemy allows me to switch the table a particular object is associated with. I think this would be the preferred solution, but I don't know if it can be done.

Another thought is that I could run a second database, and copy the deleted data over. But that adds a layer of administration complexity that I'd like to avoid.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of people do the "is_deleted" thing, and I agree I'm not a fan of that either, though we do have a recipe for that at [PreFilteredQuery](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery).

What you're looking for, as someone else suggested, is a "versioning" recipe.  We have a comprehensive example of storing copies of data in a separate versioned table introduced at [Versioned Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#versioned-objects) in the SQLAlchemy documentation.

Here, I've adapted some of the techniques used in that example to produce a more direct recipe that specifically only tracks "deleted" objects, and includes a "restore" feature which will "restore" a given row back to the main table.   So it's not as much "SQLAlchemy allows me to switch the table a particular object is associated with", it's more like another mapped class is created, which resembles the primary one, which can also be used to "reverse" the deletion as you request.  Everything below the line regarding `__main__` is a proof-of-concept.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, object_session
from sqlalchemy import event

def preserve_deleted(class_):
    def copy_col(col):
        newcol = col.copy()
        newcol.constraints = set()
        return newcol
    keys = class_.__table__.c.keys()
    cols = dict(
        (col.key, copy_col(col)) for col in class_.__table__.c
    )
    cols['__tablename__'] = "%s_deleted" % class_.__table__.name

    class History(object):
        def restore(self):
            sess = object_session(self)
            sess.delete(self)
            sess.add(copy_inst(self, class_))

    hist_class = type(
                    '%sDeleted' % class_.__name__,
                    (History, Base),
                    cols)

    def copy_inst(fromobj, tocls):
        return tocls(**dict(
                        (key, getattr(fromobj, key))
                        for key in keys
                    ))
    @event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
    def check_deleted(session, flush_context, instances):
        for del_ in session.deleted:
            if isinstance(del_, class_):
                h = copy_inst(del_, hist_class)
                session.add(h)
    class_.deleted = hist_class
    return class_

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    Base = declarative_base()

    @preserve_deleted
    class A(Base):
        __tablename__ = "a"

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        data1 = Column(String)
        data2 = Column(String)

    @preserve_deleted
    class B(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'b'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        data1 = Column(String)
        a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
        a = relationship("A")

    e = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

    Base.metadata.create_all(e)

    s = Session(e)

    a1, a2, a3, a4 = \
        A(data1='a1d1', data2='a1d2'),\
        A(data1='a2d1', data2='a2d2'),\
        A(data1='a3d1', data2='a3d2'),\
        A(data1='a4d1', data2='a4d2')

    b1, b2, b3, b4 = \
        B(data1='b1', a=a1),\
        B(data1='b2', a=a1),\
        B(data1='b3', a=a3),\
        B(data1='b4', a=a4)

    s.add_all([
        a1, a2, a3, a4,
        b1, b2, b3, b4
    ])
    s.commit()

    assert s.query(A.id).order_by(A.id).all() == [(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4, )]
    assert s.query(B.id).order_by(B.id).all() == [(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4, )]

    s.delete(a2)
    s.delete(b2)
    s.delete(b3)
    s.delete(a3)
    s.commit()

    assert s.query(A.id).order_by(A.id).all() == [(1, ), (4, )]
    assert s.query(B.id).order_by(B.id).all() == [(1, ), (4, )]

    a2_deleted = s.query(A.deleted).filter(A.deleted.id == 2).one()
    a2_deleted.restore()

    b3_deleted = s.query(B.deleted).filter(B.deleted.id == 3).one()
    a3_deleted = s.query(A.deleted).filter(A.deleted.id == 3).one()
    b3_deleted.restore()
    a3_deleted.restore()

    s.commit()

    assert s.query(A.id).order_by(A.id).all() == [(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4, )]
    assert s.query(B.id).order_by(B.id).all() == [(1, ), (3, ), (4, )]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to implement something similar to [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/).

This means you would have a table that can contain the serialized data of any other table, plus information about which table it is, etc.

Look at django-reversion's [`Version` model](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/master/src/reversion/models.py#L226) for an example.
The `content_type` field refers to a Django model that contains the model information, in your case it could just be a char field containing table names (a content type table would be better if you have a large number of tables, though).

You can then add some code so after each [insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_5/reference/orm/interfaces.html#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.after_insert) or [update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_5/reference/orm/interfaces.html#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.after_update), your version table is also updated.
Whenever you want to recover anything, you just get the serialized data from the versions table and re-insert the record.

There may be some caveats, like M2M, cascade deletes, etc. But I would start there.